# how to merge dataframes and create a nested table?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I've created several objects named 'Student' in python. Each object has attributes containing information like age, name, and gender. Besides, each object has a dataframe, which is a test grade  of a student in this year. I want to merge these dataframes and get a nested table without losing their personal information. Here's the python code:

```
import pandas as pd

class Student:
def __init__(age, name, gender, dataframe):
    self.age = age
    self.name = name
    self.gender = gender
    self.grades = dataframe

    ...
```

A dataframe looks like this:

[image]

I want to get a nested table like this:
[image]

How can I do this using Pandas? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of a nested table as per your screenshot shown, I would recommend that the `student ID, name, age, and gender` fields to all be filled-up with the same values of the same student instead.

This way, it would allow you to perform additional functions such as `groupby` aggregation as an example for further use cases.

On your question, the `subjects and marks` screenshot you shared does not have any identifying key but I would assume that you have something such as the student ID in it. Since you do not wish to lose the student information, you can simply perform a inner join that returns all the rows that matched.

There are a few merging options but `pd.merge` by default joins with a inner join:

```
merged = pd.merge(student_df, subjects_df, on = 'student_id')
```

There are other parameters for `pd.merge` that you may [find in the documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html).